# I want to destroy activities on starting a new intent

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, android-intent, activity-lifecycle

I have two activities MainActivity and signUp. MainActivity is created when application starts and it gets firebase authentication instance and if no user is found goes to signUp.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Intent intent;

FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d("MainActivity","Created..");

    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        authStateListener = firebaseAuth -> {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(user!=null) {
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeScreen.class);
                Log.d("Authentication", "User already signed in..");
                intent.putExtra("state", "alreadySignIned");
                startActivity(intent);
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        };

        intent = new Intent(this,signUp.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        MainActivity.this.finish();

        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    },5000);
}
```

}

Now when new user is registered in signUp it goes to Homescreen activity but the problem I am facing is that authStateListener is getting the user when new user is signed up and starting intent from MainActivity.

```
public class signUp extends AppCompatActivity {

Intent intent;

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
boolean buttonPress = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signup);

    EditText emailUp,passUp,userName;
    Button signUp;
    TextView toSignIn;

    emailUp = findViewById(R.id.signUpEmail);
    passUp = findViewById(R.id.signUpPass);
    signUp = findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);
    userName = findViewById(R.id.signUpUserName);
    toSignIn = findViewById(R.id.toSignIn);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    signUp.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        buttonPress = true;
        String email = emailUp.getText().toString();
        String pass = passUp.getText().toString();
        String name = userName.getText().toString();

        if(email.isEmpty()){
            emailUp.setError("Please enter email id..");
            emailUp.requestFocus();
        } else if(pass.isEmpty()){
            passUp.setError("Please enter password..");
            passUp.requestFocus();
        } else {
            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(signUp.this,"Sign up Unsuccessful, please try again.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("Authentication","User signing up..");
                    intent = new Intent(this,HomeScreen.class);
                    intent.putExtra("state","signedUp");
                    intent.putExtra("name",name);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    signUp.this.finish();
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

}

Here is the log from Homescreen activity

```
2020-05-18 14:04:33.355 29696-29696/com.example.movietracker I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@8f143e5
2020-05-18 14:05:04.668 29696-29711/com.example.movietracker D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( 82Q12yEqqjUP0AWGuGoxok4pvae2 ).
2020-05-18 14:05:04.669 29696-29711/com.example.movietracker D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying auth state listeners about user ( 82Q12yEqqjUP0AWGuGoxok4pvae2 ).
2020-05-18 14:05:04.669 29696-29696/com.example.movietracker D/Authentication: User already signed in..
2020-05-18 14:05:04.734 29696-29696/com.example.movietracker D/Homescreen Activity: Created..
2020-05-18 14:05:04.734 29696-29696/com.example.movietracker D/Intent: State alreadySignIned
2020-05-18 14:05:04.771 29696-29696/com.example.movietracker D/Cursor: Count on create 0
2020-05-18 14:05:04.773 29696-29696/com.example.movietracker D/Homescreen Activity: Started..
2020-05-18 14:05:04.773 29696-29696/com.example.movietracker D/Username: Username null
2020-05-18 14:05:04.819 29696-29696/com.example.movietracker D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-05-18 14:05:04.826 29696-29696/com.example.movietracker D/WatchList DB: Size 0
2020-05-18 14:05:04.826 29696-29696/com.example.movietracker D/WatchListID: Size 0
2020-05-18 14:05:04.838 29696-29696/com.example.movietracker D/Authentication: User signing up..
```

Here it is notifying authStateListener on sign up and after some code it is taking intent from signUp class. I want it to destroy MainActivity and directly take intent from signUp without notifying authStateListener.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MainActivity` starts `signup` `Activity` always. In the case where the user already exists, `HomeScreen` `Activity` is also launched. This is probably not what you want.

Also, the `authListener` callback calls `MainActivity.this.finish()` but by this time, `MainActivity` has already been finished so this is also wrong.

If you don't want the `authListener` to trigger when the user signs up, you should remove the listener before creating the user.

Generally speaking your code could be improved. You should look at some more tutorials for a better idea of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks I understood the problem. I didn't know about removing the listener. Now I have implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy an activity like this:

Step 1: Declare a `Activity` variable in MainActivity

```
public static Activity MainActivityContext;
```

Step 2: Initialize  `MainActivityContext` variable inside `OnCreate` Method of `MainActivity`

```
MaMainActivityContext = this;
```

Step 3: Now go to the java statement where you want to destroy `MainActivity` and write

```
MainActivity.MainActivityContext.finish();
```

Comment: You don't store a reference to an `Activity` in a `static` variable. This causes memory leaks and is just bad practice.